# permanently delete AmazonS3 folder/file from version enabled bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

We have a specific scenario in our application where we want to permanently delete a folder/file from S3 version-enabled bucket. We are using C# AWS SDK for the same. Since we have a huge data residing under the folder (ranging from 100 MB to 2.5 TB) just wanted to check if any of the below options are feasible.

> Approach 1:

Delete the folder using `S3DirectoryInfo` class of AmazonS# SDK. This puts Delete Marker recursively on top each S3Object. Now can we use S3Object Expiration Policy to permanently delete all such object? If yes, how?

> Approach 2:

Put a tag (i.e. “deleted”) just on the folder. Now can we use S3 Object Expiration Policy to permanently delete the entire folder which is tagged as "deleted"? If yes, how?

Is there any alternate solution to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious if you reached a solution for this?

Comment: @Discorick still looking for the answer :(